# How to install correct python version in my virtual env using pipenv

Tags: python, deployment, pip, ubuntu-18.04, pipenv

I'm trying to use pipenv as my primary tool for managing dependencies for a django app I'm trying to get deployed, and hitting a snag at the python version specified in the Pipfile.

The server is an ubuntu 18.04 machine where I have manually installed pip3 and pipenv. System python3 is 3.6.7, but I developed with 3.7.2 and that's what is specified in project's Pipfile. I want to use pipenv to create my virtual environment and install all dependencies in one go, including the correct python version, but I'm getting blocked when I run pipenv deploy:

```
$ pipenv install --deploy
Warning: Python 3.7 was not found on your system…
You can specify specific versions of Python with:
  $ pipenv --python path/to/python
```

Seems like a chicken vs egg issue but I'm assuming there's a best practice about deploying apps using pipenv on fresh servers that I'm missing. Will I just need to install the correct version and pass it to pipenv as an argument manually?

Comment: Just my opinion but, maybe try [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/)? I usually use that whenever I want to switch between development python versions.

Comment: Anaconda just contains a lot more software than I actually need for this deployment...I've been looking into using pyenv for switching python versions, but was hoping there was a way to do it with pipenv to reduce dependency management to one step instead of two

Comment: Python is not a dependency and `pipenv` cannot install it. If you cannot install Python 3.7 using system package manager try [tag:pyenv]. Or compile from sources. After that use it to create virtual environments.

Comment: Thanks. I think answers the questions, suppose I'll just download and install the old fashioned way. It would be cool if there were a way to install the runtime along with the dependencies but I guess it really does become a "chicken or egg" problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to install the correct version. You can refer to [pipenv document](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics/#specifying-versions-of-python).

As it said, "Pipenv will automatically scan your system for a Python that matches that given version"